# PHP error_get_last, exclude already catched exceptions

Tags: php, exception, uncaught-exception

I'm running some code, for example:

```php
register_shutdown_function("ShutdownHandler");

$var = test();

function test() {
    try {
        // Do something
        require_once("class.extra.php");
        ExtraClass::doSomething();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle the error.
        echo "exception";
        return null;
    }
    // Continue...
    return true;
}
```

class.extra.php:

```php
class ExtraClass
{
    public static function doSomething()
    {
        throw new CustomException("Exception");
    }
}

class CustomException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($mesg, $code = 0x00)
    {
        parent::__construct($mesg, $code);
    }
}
```

after some code, the script ends and the ShutdownHandler() get's called.

```php
function ShutdownHandler() {
    // error_get_last returns the already catched exception and the next if get's triggered.
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] && E_ALL) {
        // Handle the uncaught exception...
        echo "uncaught exception";
    }
}
```

But i want here only to handle uncaught exception, any ideas?

Comment: How do you want to get uncaught exception, if by definition an exception stops code from further execution if it's not caught?

Comment: @dragoste Don't understand your question. If an uncaught exception occures, the ShutdownHandler is triggered. There is further execution.

Comment: Please provide code to show how ShowdownHandler is triggered without catching the exception.

Comment: @dragoste See line 1: register_shutdown_function("ShutdownHandler");

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention you're using `register_shutdown_function()` function. Anyway still in your example there's no uncaught exception. I did some tests and I can see that **only uncaught exceptions** are returned by `get_last_error`, so I still don't know what's the problem.

Comment: @dragoste Checked it on my own with the example and indeed, there's nothing returned by `get_last_error`. I'm using in my project a library, which is accessed from inside the **try catch** block. Then a inner function of the library throws an custom exception, which extends Exception... seems like there's some code which creates this exception inside the library...

Comment: @dragoste The exception is thrown at line 54, [here](https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___transport___t_c_p.html#a86ca484fe7ecbde46d21757208aa67cb).

Comment: Exception != Error

Comment: can anyone confirm that in PHP7 ***error_get_last*** returns ***1)*** last errors ***2)*** last uncaught exceptions. Reading your comments I understand that only catched exceptions are NOT returned